# not able to find the solution on Moskito integration with java web application without Moskito UI

Tags: java, performance, maven, tomcat

1) I have done the Moskito moskito-inspect-standalone-2.5.0.war integration with Java Maven web project good.
 2) But i need to work on a plain(without Maven[pom.xml]) java web app to integrate Moskito, here even i dont need Moskito UI. i wanted to see the data in logs or some format, but not in UI

My Environment:
Windows 7
Eclipse 4.4 having a plain Java Web Application (without Maven)

How can i do monitor and inspect my classes effectively by generating log data?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can download [.jar file directly](http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/anotheria/moskito-core/2.5.0/moskito-core-2.5.0.jar) and include in your project directly. Maven is not required in this case. 
Any additional configurations (thresholds, accumulators etc.) can be found [here](https://confluence.opensource.anotheria.net/display/MSK/MoSKito-Essential+Configuration+Guide). 
To configure custom output, take a look at [configure LOG4J for Moskito](https://confluence.opensource.anotheria.net/display/MSK/Configuring+LOG4J+for+MoSKito) page, that will help you to output results wherever you want.

Comment: You can mark as 'solved my question'. Otherwise, feel free to request additional information